Prevent optimize imports for specific imports, like formatter:off
In Android Studio I've turned on optimize imports. However, there are 2 specific imports I don't want to be removed. Something similar is possible with auto-format, by using @formatter:off. Does something similar exist to prevent optimize imports?
